# How to post second question via POST call to hugginface chat?

Tags: python, post, request, huggingface

So this code works pretty good I get first desired output to the https://huggingface.co/chat/conversation/:

```
from requests.sessions import Session
from json import loads

prompt = "Explain first condition in english?"

session = Session()
session.get(url="https://huggingface.co/chat/")
res = session.post(url="https://huggingface.co/chat/conversation")
assert res.status_code == 200, "Failed to create new conversation"
conversation_id = res.json()["conversationId"]
url = f"https://huggingface.co/chat/conversation/{conversation_id}"
max_tokens = int(2000) - len(prompt)

if max_tokens > 1904:
    max_tokens = 1904

res = session.post(
    url=url,
    json={
        "inputs": prompt,
        "parameters": {
            "temperature": 0.5,
            "top_p": 0.95,
            "repetition_penalty": 1.2,
            "top_k": 50,
            "truncate": 1024,
            "watermark": False,
            "max_new_tokens": max_tokens,
            "stop": ["<|endoftext|>"],
            "return_full_text": False,
        },
        "stream": False,
        "options": {"use_cache": False},
    },
    stream=False,
)
try:
    data = res.json()
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid JSON response")
    data = {}

data = data[0] if data else {}
data.get("generated_text", "")
```

And it returns such output:

```
'Sure! The first condition you mentioned ....  Is there something specific you would like me to explain about this condition?'
```

However I dont know how to send second request?

Next code completely  ruins the chat:

```
res = session.post(
    url=url,
    json={
        "inputs": "GIVE more information",
        "parameters": {
            "temperature": 0.5,
            "top_p": 0.95,
            "repetition_penalty": 1.2,
            "top_k": 50,
            "truncate": 1024,
            "watermark": False,
            "max_new_tokens": max_tokens,
            "stop": ["<|endoftext|>"],
            "return_full_text": False,
        },
        "stream": False,
        "options": {"use_cache": False},
    },
    stream=False,
)
try:
    data = res.json()
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid JSON response")
    data = {}
    
data.get("generated_text", "")
```

Output:

```
{'error': 'Model is overloaded', 'error_type': 'overloaded'}
```